# Bitcoin mining with rented rigs

Tags: mining-profitability

Can someone please explain to me if mining with a rented rig is worth the investment. I recently mined but the server went down. Also where does the hashed data go and is it available for my viewing? Thanks so much..

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/why-would-someone-rent-hashing-power